# Valgrind Invalid read of size 1 (sscanf)

Tags: c, pointers, valgrind, scanf

Somehow Valgrind shows an error at the first lines of my program:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int i, r;
  sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &r);

  return 0;
}
```

Valgrind reports:

```
==18674== Invalid read of size 1
==18674==    at 0x4ECB1A0: rawmemchr (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.23.so)
==18674==    by 0x4EB2F41: _IO_str_init_static_internal (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.23.so)
==18674==    by 0x4EA16C6: __isoc99_vsscanf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.23.so)
==18674==    by 0x4EA1666: __isoc99_sscanf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.23.so)
==18674==    by 0x400DE3: main (test_b_arbre.c:18)
==18674==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==18674== 
==18674== 
==18674== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==18674==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==18674==    at 0x4ECB1A0: rawmemchr (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.23.so)
==18674==    by 0x4EB2F41: _IO_str_init_static_internal (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.23.so)
==18674==    by 0x4EA16C6: __isoc99_vsscanf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.23.so)
==18674==    by 0x4EA1666: __isoc99_sscanf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.23.so)
==18674==    by 0x400DE3: main (test_b_arbre.c:18)
```

I went through some similar questions, but I didn't find how to fix it...
How I run the program:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./b_arbre 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Do you have `#include <stdio.h>` in the program?

Comment: @Barmar It's required, but a red herring to this issue.

Comment: Valgrind shows the error in `test_b_arbre.c`. Perhaps you posted code that you simplified too much in this post when the underlying answer was in the code in that file?

Comment: @LeoCHan test_b_arbre.c is the main program

Comment: _Access not within mapped region at address **0x0**_ : Probably `argv[1]` is `NULL`.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand Is the code you're showing the exact same code inside `test_b_arbre.c`? There's actually nothing wrong with the example you gavee in the post, but I think it would help if you gave us the actual code.

Comment: I think you should review the command line you think you're using.  The error is because `argv[1] == NULL`, but you shouldn't have that condition if you're providing the numbers as input.  Add debugging printing to your program: `printf("argc = %d\n", argc); for (int j = 0; j < argc; j++) printf("argv[%d] = [%s]\n", j, argv[j]);` to see what that thinks you're getting as command line arguments.  You could/should check the return value from `sscanf()`, but the damage is being done before it returns, so it isn't immediately a factor in your problem.

Comment: @DavidBowling Although of course the return value of `sscanf` ought to be checked, it has nothing to do with the Valgrind report, which shows something bad happening before `sscanf` has had a chance to return a value.  That situation cannot happen in the above program, if it is really called with those arguments, and the Linux installation isn't borked in some strange way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled your exact program on a 64 bit x86_64 Linux (seeing hints of 64 bit libraries in your Valgrind output). The issue doesn't reproduce. I get a warning about the `sscanf` implicit declaration not being correct, but that is a red herring.

I also tried on 64 bit Power PC Linux. Clean Valgrind also.

(Of course, the null pointer dereference occurs if the program is called with no arguments, in which case `argv[argc]` is done; but the issue is described as occurring **with** arguments.)

The problem is likely that the executable being tested doesn't match the source code.

Comment: Somehow I placed the file somewhere else and called it from there and there was no problem... Just some LinuxFedora curiosity I guess.. Thanks for this simple idea

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking it with no arguments, so `argv[1]` is a null pointer.  "Fix" it by providing a command line argument.  Fix it properly by checking `argc` and doing something else when it is 1.

Comment: I have arguments, r does have the right value of 1 when I check it

Comment: @PaulLemarchand  Your `r` doesn't receive a value unless `sscanf` successfully executes. But `sscanf` is hitting a null pointer dereference inside, according to the Valgrind report.  If you look into `r` before it has received a value, it has "indeterminate" contents.